# How can I download all of this JPL MRO imaging data at once?

Tags: mars, data-analysis, nasa

There are several files. I think that they all needs to downloaded to have the complete dataset. Is there a particularly good way to download them all in one shot?

- https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/volumes/mro/release50.html

The page shows over 100 individual icons, one for each volume.

[image]

Comment: The data seems to have consistent file naming, so you could script it, or you could use something like `wget -m`. I'm guessing there is a LOT of data there, so make sure you have the disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** do it, I will leave you to decide whether you should... As an experiment, I downloaded the `mrox_3374` subdirectory of files and the result came out to 3.7 GB. Assuming the other 99 "volumes"/directories are the same, this multiplies out to 370 GB.

I downloaded these data using `wget` which is a standard utility on Unix/Linux and Mac computers. It is also available for Windows systems; this [Wget for Windows 10 tutorial](https://builtvisible.com/download-your-website-with-wget/) should be of some help in getting it installed and going.

Once this is installed you can do:

```
wget -np -nH -c --cut-dirs 4 -r https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/data/mro/mars_reconnaissance_orbiter/ctx/mrox_3374/
```

The key flags are `-r` which means recurse into directories, `-np` which means don't ascend to the parent directory (to stop it sucking down the entire website), `-c` which will continue the transfer if it fails and you restart the `wget` and the `--cut-dirs 4` which cuts 4 levels of the directories off the recursive download (the `data/mro/mars_reconnaissance_orbiter/ctx` parts)

If you **really, really** want to suck down the whole thing you *could* do:

```
wget -np -nH -c --cut-dirs 3 -r https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/data/mro/mars_reconnaissance_orbiter/ctx/
```

and that should grab everything.

Comment: Success! I needed only one volume. Window 10 ( or may be my work place firewall) created some some hiccups. It would tell in the middle of execution that "wget has stopped working" . I started the program 4 times  and thanks to wget robustness each time it started where it had left. (got volume 3448, 1.83GB).

Comment: I use these datasets.  CTX has a data volume of >10TB, while MARCI is closer to around 1TB (significant rounding involved in these numbers).  That is just the real data - the .IMG files.  Add to that all the preview/browse data and you need more space.  As of PDS release 51, CTX has around 106,000 .IMG files, and MARCI is the same to within 1000-2000.